# Inform Jackson to throw exception if Json does not match expected object structure

Tags: java, json, jackson

Using this code to convert convert Json to a Java object using Jackson annotations :

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import objectmappertest.Request;
import java.io.IOException;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        final String json  = "{\"datePurchased\":\"2022-02-03 21:32:017\"},{\"unknownField\":\"test\"}";
        final Request request = mapper.readValue(json, Request.class);
        System.out.println("request : "+request);
    }
```

I expect an exception to be thrown as the Request Java object does not contain a field type `unknownField` , instead it seems that Jackson parses what it can from the JSON. Is there a configuration option which a causes an exception or a flag to be set if the Json being passed to Jackson does not match the Java object structure ?

Here is the expected structure :

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
import lombok.extern.jackson.Jacksonized;
import java.util.Date;

@Builder
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@Jacksonized
public class Request
{
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:sss")
    private final Date datePurchased;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES**

> Feature that determines whether encountering of unknown properties
> (ones that do not map to a property, and there is no "any setter" or
> handler that can handle it) should result in a failure (by throwing a
> JsonMappingException) or not.

Example of Usage:

```
   ObjectMapper mapper  = new ObjectMapper();
   mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true);
```

Documentation:

https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html

---

You can also use the annotation `@JsonIgnoreProperties` on top of the POJO itself:  However I am not quite sure if this will throw an Exception on its own.

```
@Target(value={ANNOTATION_TYPE,TYPE,METHOD,CONSTRUCTOR,FIELD})
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
public @interface JsonIgnoreProperties
Annotation that can be used to either suppress serialization of properties (during serialization), or ignore processing of JSON properties read (during deserialization).
```

Example:

```
 // To throw exception on any unknown properties in JSON input:
 @JsonIgnoreProperties
 public class YourPoJo{
        
 }
```

---

```
public abstract boolean ignoreUnknown
```

> Property that defines whether it is ok to just ignore any unrecognized
> properties during deserialization.
>
> If true, all properties that are unrecognized -- that is, there are no
> setters or creators that accept them -- are ignored without warnings
> (although handlers for unknown properties, if any, will still be
> called) without exception.
>
> **Does not have any effect on serialization.**
>
> Default: false

Documentation: http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html